# ajaxForm change value after submit form

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

I have the following code in jquery, that is supposed to update a hidden field when the form is submitted, and the process the form with the new value.

```
$("#" + id).ajaxForm({
    beforeSubmit: function() {
        $("#" + id + " input[type=submit]").attr('disabled', true);
        $("#" + id + " img.loader").show();

        $.get('/getProd.php?refNumber='+$("#" + id + " input[name='refNumber']").val(), function (data) {
            $("#" + id + " input[name='productID']").val(data);
        });
        alert("done pre");
    },  
    success: function(resp) {
        $("#" + id + " input[type=submit]").attr('disabled', false);
        $("#" + id + " img.loader").hide();
        resp = eval('(' + resp + ')');
        ccm_parseJSON(resp, function() {
            alert('done');
        });
    }
});
```

My problem is that the submitted value that is being used is the old one. How do I make the success use the new value that I insert with the line

```
$("#" + id + " input[name='productID']").val(data);
```

?

Thanks.

Comment: Question : from what I read, you don't need the `productID` to identify the product, you just need the `refNumber`. Why don't you change your server side treatment to take into account the `refNumber`, rather than the `productID` ?

Comment: I need the productId, the page getProd.php converts the refNumber to the productId for me. It needs to be run server side

Comment: I managed, take a look at my answer below

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the problem was that the ajax was using async (as it should).

It basically was finishing the query to the server after the function finished.

So, I set before my ajax call

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        async: false
    });
```

and after my ajax call

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        async: true
    });
```

and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

(following comment)

That's what I mean : why don't you

1. send your form content to the server, with the correct `refNumber`,
2. on the server side, call `getProd.php` (or whatever function is coded inside it) to get  the correct `productID`,
3. proceed with the correct `productID` ?

It would save one extra back & forth from the client.

Comment: That would not work since I cannot modify the script that uses the productId to use the refNumber. I basically send it to two different locations. I solved my problem, take a look above.
Thanks!

Comment: you have extra constraints. ok